# Running into Internal Server Error (500) and typeerror for authentication method on rails-react app when deployed on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby, heroku

I am getting a 500 error for my authentication method (trying to log in).
I've been trying things for these few days, and getting frustrated so I'm reaching out for help!
It is odd because it is working perfectly when I do it locally, but only doesn't work when I try to do it on a deployed app.
I'm using a react - rails on ruby app.

On the console, it shows:

```
POST https://bookend-app-api.herokuapp.com/users/login 500 (Internal Server Error)
(anonymous) @ Home.jsx:40
Home.jsx:52 error SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at Home.jsx:41
```

And here is my heroku log:

```
2020-10-21T08:09:08.910811+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 4.3.5 (ruby 2.6.3-p62), codename: Mysterious Traveller
2020-10-21T08:09:08.910813+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2020-10-21T08:09:08.910813+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2020-10-21T08:09:08.911143+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:9349
2020-10-21T08:09:08.911592+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2020-10-21T08:09:09.393243+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-10-21T08:09:10.436899+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-10-21T08:09:10.436789 #4]  INFO -- : [e98560d0-f62c-4654-ab05-7b648397778e] Started POST "/users/login" for 39.123.239.97 at 2020-10-21 08:09:10 +0000
2020-10-21T08:09:10.444498+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-10-21T08:09:10.444415 #4]  INFO -- : [e98560d0-f62c-4654-ab05-7b648397778e] Processing by UsersController#login as */*
2020-10-21T08:09:10.444554+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-10-21T08:09:10.444507 #4]  INFO -- : [e98560d0-f62c-4654-ab05-7b648397778e]   Parameters: {"user"=>{"username"=>"katy", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
2020-10-21T08:09:10.516954+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2020-10-21T08:09:10.516828 #4] DEBUG -- : [e98560d0-f62c-4654-ab05-7b648397778e]   User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["username", "katy"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2020-10-21T08:09:10.844349+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users/login" host=bookend-app-api.herokuapp.com request_id=e98560d0-f62c-4654-ab05-7b648397778e fwd="39.123.239.97" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=407ms status=500 bytes=374 protocol=https
2020-10-21T08:09:10.840623+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-10-21T08:09:10.840511 #4]  INFO -- : [e98560d0-f62c-4654-ab05-7b648397778e] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 396ms (ActiveRecord: 30.4ms | Allocations: 8446)
2020-10-21T08:09:10.841215+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-10-21T08:09:10.841144 #4] FATAL -- : [e98560d0-f62c-4654-ab05-7b648397778e]
2020-10-21T08:09:10.841216+00:00 app[web.1]: [e98560d0-f62c-4654-ab05-7b648397778e] TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):
2020-10-21T08:09:10.841217+00:00 app[web.1]: [e98560d0-f62c-4654-ab05-7b648397778e]
```

My application-controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API

    def authenticate_token
        # puts "AUTHENTICATE JWT"
        render json: { status: 401, message: 'Unauthorized' } unless decode_token(bearer_token)
    end
  
    def bearer_token
        # puts "BEARER TOKEN"
        header = request.env["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"]

        pattern = /^Bearer /
        # puts "TOKEN WITHOUT BEARER"
        header.gsub(pattern, '') if header && header.match(pattern)
    end
  
    def decode_token(token_input)
        # puts "DECODE TOKEN, token input: #{token_input}"
        # token =
        JWT.decode(token_input, ENV['JWT_SECRET'], true)
        # render json: { decoded: token }
    rescue
        render json: { status: 401, message: 'Unauthorized' }                          
    end

    def get_current_user 
        return if !bearer_token   
        decoded_jwt = decode_token(bearer_token) 
        User.find(decoded_jwt[0]["user"]["id"])
    end 

    def authorize_user
        render json: { status: 401, message: "Unauthorized" } unless get_current_user.id == params[:id].to_i       
    end

    # delete if error occurs
    def session_user
        decoded_hash = decoded_token
        if !decoded_hash.empty?
            user_id = decoded_hash[0]['user_id']
            @user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
        else
            nil
        end
    end
    # 
  
  end
```

application.rb:

```
require_relative 'boot'

require "rails"
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"
require "active_storage/engine"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_mailbox/engine"
require "action_text/engine"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "action_cable/engine"
# require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module BookwormAppApi
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 6.0

    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration can go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded after loading
    # the framework and any gems in your application.

    # Only loads a smaller set of middleware suitable for API only apps.
    # Middleware like session, flash, cookies can be added back manually.
    # Skip views, helpers and assets when generating a new resource.
    config.api_only = true

    config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Also, this is the block of code in Home.jsx describing the POST method used to log in and where it's giving a typeerror. (this typeerror doesn't occur locally.)

```
useEffect(()=>{
        if(loginInfo.username !== undefined){
        let requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: LoginFormdata,
        redirect: 'follow'
        };
        
        fetch(`${apiUrl}/users/login`, requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
            console.log('FETCH (post) (login) from home', result)
            if (result.status==200){
                authorization(result.token, result.user.id)
                handleAuthenInfoFromApp(result.token, result.user.id)
            }
            else{
                setLoginSuccessful(false)
            }
        })
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
        }
    }, [loginInfo])
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to increase the log level (even do it looks like debugs are showing ... but no error traces), or use something like the exception_notification gem (https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification) that will send you the error and it trace by email.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with ruby, but from what I can make up out of the error and the react part is that there are no authorisation headers added to the fetch method options. I'd suggest doing the following:

1: Use postman to verify your request. Set all the headers, body, authorisation. Postman helps you a little bit with authorisation headers, they can be confusing.

2: Look at the postman headers and make sure all of them are the same in the fetch headers in js.

3: Add headers in the way that is described by [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Headers)